# Apache Meter - remove trailing slash on request url

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to make a request but it kept failing, it turn out that Apache JMeter is appending a "/" in the request as seen the View Result Listener > Request.

How do you disable that?Thanks!

Comment: What version of JMeter do you use, what sampler, how do you construct request?

Comment: Its JMeter 2.10.  I construct it using HTTP request.

Answer (score 3):

Put " ? " at the end of your request url.

Request url: www.stackoverflow.com/questions?

JMeter Url will be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?/

Answer (score 2):

For thoose who search an easy way, here it is :

1. In the HTTP Request, just put the server name in the "Server Name or IP"
2. Add the rest of the path in "Path"

This should works :)

source: http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Trailing-slashes-appended-to-webservice-path-tp5720633p5720638.html

Answer (score 0):

What is your request path? If it's empty, it's absolutely expected that JMeter adds slash to your path.

From [HTTPSamplerBase](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html):

```
// HTTP URLs must be absolute, allow file to be relative
        if (!path.startsWith("/")){ // $NON-NLS-1$
            pathAndQuery.append("/"); // $NON-NLS-1$
        }
```

In any case trailing slash shouldn't cause any error.

If you're getting your path from a variable or dynamically constructing it you should be able to remove the slash via i.e. [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) as follows:

Assuming that you have a JMeter Variable called "PATH" containing your path.

```
String path = vars.get("PATH");
if (path.endsWith("/")) {
    vars.put("PATH",path.substring(0,path.length()-1));
}
```

Once again, slash at the path end shouldn't be the reason for test failure.

Comment: unfortunately, i'm not the dev of the API.  I'm just calling it, and it fails on JMeter because of the slash, but works fine on rest client where no slash is being appended.  I would like to know how can i put my request url in PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the proper **HTTP Header Manager** ? Its required for a HTTP Request sampler. "/" should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put your full url (include http:// or http:// in front of url)  in the path field instead of the server name + path approach. The getUrl method in the HTTPSamplerBase.java bypasses url creation if it detects http or https in front of the url and this way the slash is not automatically appended to the end of the url. Took me a while of reading the docs and java code to figure out.

See getUrl method implementation in the following [link](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/82853fbadd720fb6cd0a7f02cef36eab96ebd39f/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.java#L1064)